# .net + SQL + Timeout issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, timeout

I'm having an issue with a .net library connecting to an SQL Server instance.

The library is part of an application which inserts the contents of edi files into an SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Every time the library is called, it throws an exception (#1 below) stating that the connection has timed out.  There are multiple other non .net applications on the server in question which use the same connection string and work perfectly.

I have also installed the application containing the library on another networked machine and it works fine from there.

Things I have tried:

> Setting .CommandTimeout = 150; - Times out way before 150 secs.
>   Reinstalling all .net frameworks
>   Rebooting app server & DB server
>   Switching from data context to standard data adapter queries.
>   Created a stand alone exe to test connection string using both data context and standard data adapter queries - Both methods fail first time, but then connect and read data on all subsequent tries until the exe is restarted.  This lead me to add a retry attempt with a delay to the library when the exception is hit, but that results in exception 2.

I'm now at a loss.  Any help would be appreciated.

Exception 1:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
  at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteQuery[TResult](String query, Object[] parameters)

<Query Execution method call>
```

Exception 2:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteQuery[TResult](String query, Object[] parameters)

<Query Execution method call>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Setting .CommandTimeout

occurs when a query can't get total data with in the specified time..

In your case,there can be many time outs which can occur ..We solved the time out approach in our case ,by following below steps

1.Changed RemoteLoginTimeout to 60
2.Change RemoteQuery timeout to 0..

Further  we also disabled TCP Chimney on all of our servers

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2010/02/21/tcp-offloading-again/

Now we are 100% sure ,network is not a factor in time outs,even then if the query fails with time  out,when executed though SQLagent or some thing else

1.We try to update statistics
2.We will see ,if there is a chance for optimization..

You also can refer to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattn/2008/08/29/sqlclient-timeouts-revealed/),where OP mentioned all the time outs that can occur

> When attempting to get a connection from the SqlClient connection pool
>   When attempting to create a new fresh connection to server (not getting one from pool)
>   When sending a command explicitly to the server
>   When sending commands with "context connection=true"
>   When sending commands implicitly (under the covers) to the server
>   When executing asynchronous commands (BeginExecute…)
>   When waiting for attention acknowledgement from server (special rare case)
>   When sending TM commands
>   When fetching rows
>   When uploading rows using bulk copy